# How to register keyboard key only after being held for 0.5 second for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a simple html page with an input field and I want the input field to register input only after a key was held down for 0.5 second. In other words, in order for a character to be registered, the user has to hold it down for at least 0.5 seconds.

I have tries the following code and works ok for desktop, but when I tried it on iOS and Android it didn't work. My guess is that the keydown function is fired only when the user releases the key since the soft keyboard has some type of special behaviour when held down.

This is the html

```html
<h1 id="hello">Hello</h1>
<input type="text" id="Box">
```

and this is the script

```
var downTime = 0;
var currKeycode = 0;
var allowed = ['KeyA','KeyB','KeyC','KeyD','KeyE','KeyF','KeyG','KeyH','KeyI','KeyJ','KeyK', 'KeyL', 'KeyM', 'KeyN', 'KeyO', 'KeyP','KeyQ','KeyR', 'KeyS','KeyT','KeyU','KeyV', 'KeyW','KeyX', 'KeyY',  'KeyZ']

document.getElementById("Box").addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (allowed.includes(e.code)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = e.code

        if (currKeycode == e.code && downTime != 0) {
            var curTime = new Date();
            if (curTime - downTime > 100) {
                document.getElementById("Box").value = document.getElementById("Box").value + e.key;
                downTime = 0;
            }
        } else {
            downTime = new Date();
            currKeycode = e.code;
        }
        console.log("hello " + e.code);
    }
});

document.getElementById("Box").addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (allowed.includes(e.code)) {
        var curr = new Date();
        if (curr - downTime > 100) {
            document.getElementById("Box").value = document.getElementById("Box").value + e.key;
        }
        console.log("bye " + e.code);
    }
    downTime = 0;

});
```

Is there a solution to this problem?
Thanks.

**EDIT :**

I used the line

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = e.code
```

To check when the `keydown` method was called, and it was only called after I released the key. (Only when testing on mobile).

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not related to JavaScript specifically, but apparently according to the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands), `keyDown`, in general, is fired if the key is continually pressed.

So simply

```js
var startedDown, timeWhenStarted;
test.onkeydown = e => {
  if(!startedDown) {
    timeWhenStarted = Date.now();
    startedDown = true
  }
  
  if(Date.now() - timeWhenStarted < 500) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  
  startedDown = false;/*if you want the 
  delay to apply for every key press, 
  if you just want it to apply for every time
  the box is focused, then put this line in 
  a onblur event instead to reset it, or in 
  a keyup event if you want the delay to happen
  every time one starts typing after holding down 
  a key*/
  
};
```

```html
<input id=test>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that when I test on a mobile phone (iOS and Android), the `keydown` method is fired only after I release the key.

Comment: @kr3mbo OK if thats the case then there's nothing you can do with javascript, short of designing your own on-screen keyboard to display in the browser window (perhaps with position:fixed). In other words, its not a javascript / html question or issue, its just the way the current keyboard app for mobile is made, and that itself can't be changed